# trying to make two different buttons for restart & restart later in NSIS

Tags: nsis

As i am working with the NSIS code, i was trying to make two different buttons for restart & restart later in NSIS. Based on the nsis Docuementaion
we need to use following commands(MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTNOW,MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTLATER)
But i was getting an error called "macro named MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTNOW. not found". Could you plese let me know how can we do this tricky task.

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTNOW "Yes, restart the computer now"

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTLATER "No, I will restart the computer later"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTNOW

!insertmacro MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTLATER

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------

Section test
SectionEnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are defines to customize the page, not macros you can call.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_REBOOTLATER_DEFAULT ; Make "later" the default option
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TEXT_REBOOTNOW "Reboot now!!!!" ; Custom text
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Section
Sleep 2222
SetRebootFlag True # Pretend we did something that requires a reboot
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anders for your brief explaination & fastest response!.. Your suggessions are always make the perfect Solution of my problem.